# How to "poke" users on different SE sites

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

(Note: this question is slightly tl:dr but to sum up, I'm interested in figuring out how to increase the quality of the site's questions. The following is the reasoning I worked out)

This is *poke*, on Facebook.

http://wiloooo.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/Facebook-Poke-Icon.png

According to the Facebook help page, its main purpose is to give a notification to the user I "poked".

*Why do I ask this?* Well... let's see the following facts:

1. There are a lot of people at Super User that have accounts on other Stack Exchange sites.
2. There are a lot of people that are more active on other Stack Exchange sites than Super User.

(This problem can be transversal to all sites, but I'm posting here, instead of Meta Stack Overflow as I found this problem here first).

According to 1. if they had the commitment to join Super User, then those peoples also have an interest in asking or answering questions.

The problem is that there are some people that **ask questions** and afterwards stop visiting SU. They don't stop being active in Stack Exchange as stated in 2. (in fact, they are quite active on Stack Overflow, for most of the users I checked), but they stop being active on SU.

**Why is this a problem?**  If the problem was about answers given, there exists a quite nice setup (editing, reviewing, getting compensation for improving a post) designed to increase the quality and therefore the signal to noise ratio on the site. However the same can not be said about questions.

I can divide most questions here on 2 types:

- Generalist, easy access and wide answering questions (e.g. "How to *daggertooth* my *jabberwocky* without using the *flux capacitor*"). These kinds of questions, when even written with some detail, can be fixed and therefore can be of more use to the community.
- Specific, very strict and single answer questions (e.g. "Installation of *localaxis* failed because error *not an axis* was given") These kinds of questions rarely have more than a single answer, and most times the answer is specific to the problems faced by that user and rarely to a greater audience.

The latter can't be reformatted without the author. Unless we can open his head remotely and see what the actual question is, these kinds of questions, if having content issues that not condemning it to oblivion but make it incomplete or hard to understand, can't be easily edited.

Furthermore, what if someone has answered the question, and the author fails to give it attention? The people that gave an answer have some expectation that the person who did take the time to write a question can retribute the time that the persons that answered took.

In fact, this is how this problem came to be, for me. I checked my answers for some information I had and that wanted to adapt to an answer. For pure curiosity, I checked some of my "inactive" answers and I found that the authors of the respective questions, although inactive in SU, are active on other SE sites.

**What I'm not asking:** I ***don't*** want a *poke* feature like the one on Facebook (that was merely to illustrate/bold the post), but I'm interested in knowing of *good* ways to *call back* the users, to give a little attention to the questions.

I know that regardless of site, the user does receive a little red dot on the left upper corner stating someone somewhere answered the question. But for this to happen, the users might simply *forget* or *disregard* fully the question they themselves asked.

Signaling in with @(someone's_name) in a comment box seems to be somewhat like a plea for attention (emphasis on the plea). I could open a private chat room with the user, but that seems even worse.

The most "delicate" way I came across of signaling this is to... say, if the question is standing still in 2 weeks time, then a new notification should be sent to the user, maybe saying something in the order of "Hey, someone answered your post and you haven't done anything about it".

Comment: The inbox *already* works across the whole network. A comment on SuperUser is seen when visiting Stack Overflow.

Comment: I know about that, but it is incredibly easy to disregard a notification.

Comment: Please also add "Trout Slap".

Comment: @DoktoroReichard So how would this be any different.  If people aren't interested, they aren't interested.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard But what if the person is trying to disregard *you*? :P

Comment: And poking cannot be disregarded? You cannot **force** people to participate.

Comment: What if they stopped using the site?

Comment: Lets turn it into a social network while we're at it.

Comment: @JoshC Good idea! [Here's my first status update](https://www.facebook.com/andy.barber/posts/10151631066291082)

Comment: It's true that I can't **force** people to participate, but they are the ones asking the questions. Shouldn't they have the littlest bit of interest in seeing them solved?

Comment: @DoktoroReichard Yes, they should. But no, you should not be able to bug them about it. And this would be used for far more than that, even if this were a good reason for it.

Comment: @JoshC - Can we also add a feature to broadcast every post to all of our followers? And perhaps email. Definitely need some sort of private messaging. And more images, perhaps a list of galleries.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: *friend request sent* /jk

Comment: @JoshC (poke) haha. I just **liked** your previous comment! Can't wait to see a shared status update on your timeline so I can retweet it with my witty but useless hashtag!

Comment: I stopped reading at this point: *`This is poke, on Facebook.`*

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about poking

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No.

There is no reason to add this feature, whatsoever.

A comment on a post on SuperUser goes into the global inbox, and will be seen by the user when visiting *any* site in the Stack Exchange network where the user has a linked account. **That is enough of a poke**.

You cannot force anyone to participate. Additional poking is not going to motivate people any more than a regular comment would.

Comment: As I stated, I wasn't asking for a outright *poke*, but a reminder.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard - Reminder: accept an answer.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard: Yes, I know. That reminder is still a poke, an automated one.

Comment: @TravisJ: Reminder: poke the OP again in 8 minutes when the question is at least 15 minutes old, to remind him to accept an answer.

Comment: Please, we don't need reminders to accept an answer, especially within 15 minutes. Just let it be. If you see the user has accepted *any* answers, they know the feature exists.

Comment: To at least make some closure about this topic. I didn't ask for a feature like "poke" to be added (there are enough similar topics around here), I asked whether there were more subtle ways to make someone participate (but as shown in comments, people stopped reading after the first lines). However, and as the community shows, you can't really force anyone to participate. I'm accepting your answer at it shows the generalized community's view on this topic.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard: I understood that you didn't want a feature for people to 'poke' someone, you wanted the *system* to poke someone. I just don't think that that is needed.

Answer (score 5):

a big **NO** to poke someone as stackoverflow is maintained by people who voluntarily contributing and helping others, and this is not a social network and people are not ask to help they do whenever they are available and the want.

Comment: And I'm not asking for a *poke*, nor a social network, but rather for a way to remind people.

Comment: Yes you are. You are asking for a poke.

Comment: If I were asking for a "poke" I would have tagged it as *feature-request*. Instead, I tagged it as *discussion* because I wanted to know if, besides the examples I gave, there were better ways to "remember" people. But the reading skills of most viewers seem to deplete as soon as they read the first lines.